# Moving files inside a tar archive

Tags: bash, gzip, tar

I have a script that archives a mongo collection:

archive.tar.gz contains:

```
folder/file.bson
```

and I need to add a additional top level folder to that structure, example:

```
top-folder/folder/file.bson
```

It seems that one way is to unpack and re-pack everything but is there any other solution to this ?
The problem is that there's is a third party script that unpacks the archive and fetches the files from top-folder/folder/file.bson and in current formal, the path is wrong.

Comment: Do you use GNU tar? Can you add an option to the third party script when unpacking?

Comment: From my point of view, that's all you can do: `tar ... archive.tar.gz | tar ... new_archive.tar.gz`

Comment: Yes, it's GNU tar and i can't really change the third party script (the script must work with all the archives from the beginning of time and I have a couple of months with a wrong path inside)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`.tar.gz` is actually what the name suggests - first `tar` converts a directory structure to a byte stream (i.e. a single file), and this byte stream is then compressed by `gzip`.

Which means that changing the file path inside the archive is equal to byte-editing a compressed data stream - an unnecessarily difficult thing to do without decompressing the stream.

Comment: Thank you - it seems that all I have to do is to repack everything that has a wrong path :( - or I can make a post-script that checks for the path and moves the files if the path is wrong.